# Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

Tags: node.js, ajax, handlebars.js, jwt

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent. I hate this problem because get it many times and I though that I found my mistake,but I was wrong.
Okay this my code.

```
const mongoose = require ("mongoose");
const Spec = require("./specialist");
const Person = require("./person");
const Company = require("./company");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");

module.exports.findUser=function(username,callback){
    let query = {email_num:username};
    Spec.findOne(query,(err_spec,spec_user)=>{
        if(err_spec) throw err_spec;
        if(!spec_user){
            Person.findOne(query,(err_person,person_user)=>{
                if(err_person) throw err_person;
                if(!person_user){
                    Company.findOne(query,(err_company,company_user)=>{
                        if(err_company) throw err_company;
                        if(!company_user){
                            return console.log("Error User Not Found");
                        }
                        return callback(null,company_user);
                    });
                }
                return callback(null,person_user);
            });
        }
        return callback(null,spec_user);
    });
};
module.exports.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, hash, callback){
    bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, hash, (err, isMatch) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    callback(null, isMatch);
    });
};
module.exports.saveToken = function(username,role,token,callback){
    let query = {email_num:username};
    let updateToken={updatedToken:token};
    if(role==="Person-User"){
        Person.findOneAndUpdate(query,updateToken,callback);
    }else if(role==="Specialist-User"){
        Spec.findOneAndUpdate(query,updateToken,callback);
    }else if(role==="Company-User"){
        Company.findOneAndUpdate(query,updateToken,callback);
    }else{
        console.log("Something went goes wrong");
    }

}
```

I've created 3 collections and this file for handling them all.
This is my main server code.

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const handlebars = require("express-handlebars");
const app = express();
const passport = require('passport');
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");

const config = require("./config/data");
const routes = require("./routes/users");
const company = require("./routes/company");
const person = require("./routes/person");
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

let options = {
    useMongoClient: true,
    reconnectTries: Number.MAX_VALUE, 
    reconnectInterval: 500, 
    poolSize: 10,
    bufferMaxEntries: 0
  };

mongoose.connect(config.database,options);

let db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
 console.log( `DB connected ${new Date()}...`);
});


//app.set('views',__dirname+'views');
app.engine('handlebars', handlebars({defaultLayout:false}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// app.use(cors());
app.use(cookieParser());

// Passport Middleware
// require('./config/passport')(passport);
app.use(passport.initialize());

app.use(passport.session());


app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    res.render("index");
});

// app.get("/forgotPass",(req,res)=>{
//     res.render("forgotPass");
// });
app.get("/user", (req,res)=>{
    res.render("user");
});

app.get("/login",(req,res)=>{
    res.render("login");
});
app.get("/signup",(req,res)=>{
    res.render("signup");
});
app.get("/we",(req,res)=>{
    res.render("we");
});
app.get("/blog",(req,res)=>{
    res.render("blog");
});
app.get("/contactUs",(req,res)=>{
    res.render("contactUs");
});
app.get("/userAsApplicant",(req,res)=>{
    res.render("userAsApplicant");
});
app.use("/users",routes);
app.use("/company",company);
app.use("/person",person);
app.get("/faq",(req,res)=>{
    res.render("faq");
});
app.listen(config.port,()=>{
    console.log(`Server running on port ${config.port}....`);
});
```

Also for many form handler I'm using Ajax for all requests.

```
 $(function () {
    $('.subForm').on('submit', function (e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/users/spec/register',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success:function(data){
                if(data.success){
                    location.href="http://localhost:3000/login"
                }else{
                    location.href="http://localhost:3000/signup"
                }
            }  
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });

        $('.personAuth').on('submit', function (e) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'http://localhost:3000/person/register',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success:function(data){
                    if(data.success){
                        location.href="http://localhost:3000/login"
                    }else{
                        console.log("Chexav");
                        location.href="http://localhost:3000/signup";

                    }
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
        $('.companyAuth').on('submit', function (e) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'http://localhost:3000/company/register',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success:function(data){
                    if(data.success){
                        location.href="http://localhost:3000/login"
                    }else{
                        location.href="http://localhost:3000/signup"
                    }
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
        $('.logInForm').on('submit', function (e) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'http://localhost:3000/users/authenticate',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success:function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    if(data.token){
                        localStorage.setItem("Authorization",data.token);
                        $.ajax({
                            type:'get',
                            url:'http://localhost:3000/users/user',
                            beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('auth', localStorage.getItem("Authorization"));},
                            success:location.href="http://localhost:3000/users/user"
                        })
                    }
                }    
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });

    });
```

And this route for authentication.

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const Spec = require("../models/specialist");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const config = require("../config/data");
const Model = require("../models/model");

    //Registration route
    router.post("/spec/register",(req,res)=>{
        let date=new Date();
        let newUser = new Spec({
            name:req.body.spec_name,
            email_num:req.body.spec_email,
            password:req.body.spec_password,
            role:"Specialist-User",
            isActive:true,
            created:date,
            updatedToken:"JWT"

        });
        if(newUser.password===req.body.spec_confirmPass){
            Spec.getUser(newUser.email_num,(error,user)=>{
                if(error) throw error;
                if(!user){
                    Spec.addUser(newUser,(err,user)=>{
                        if(err){
                            console.log("err");
                            res.json({success:false,msg:"Somethings Went Wrong"});
                        } else {
                            res.header("Content-Type","application/json");
                            res.json({success:true,msg:"User Registered"});
                        // res.redirect("/login");
                        }
                    });
                }else{
                   res.json({success:false,msg:"User Already Exists"});
                }
            });
        }else{
            res.json({success:false,msg:"Password Not Confirmed"});
        }
    });


     //Authentication route
router.post('/authenticate', (req, res,next) => {
        const email = req.body.email;
        const password = req.body.password;
        console.log("UserData");
        Model.findUser(email, (err, user) => {
            console.log("UserData1");
          if(err) throw err;
          if(!user){
            return res.json({success: false, msg: 'User not found'});
          }
          Model.comparePassword(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
            console.log("UserData2");
            if(err) throw err;
            if(isMatch){
              let payload={
                name:user.name,
                email:user.email_num,
                role:user.role,
                deleted:user.deleted,
                isActive:user.isActive,
                created:user.created,
              };
              let token = jwt.sign(payload,config.JWT_SECRET,{
                  expiresIn:1440
              });

                Model.saveToken(email,user.role,token,(err,success)=>{
                    if(err) return err;
                    console.log("Success");
                    // res.setHeader('Authorization',token);
                    // res.cookie('Authorization',token);
                    res.json ({ success: true, token: token });
                    // res.redirect("/users/user");
                }); 


            } else {
              return res.json({success: false, msg: 'Wrong password'});
            }
      });
   });
// res.redirect("/user");
 });

 router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.headers);
    let token = req.body.token || req.headers['auth'] || req.query.token || req.cookies.Authorization;
    // console.log(token);
      if (token) {
        jwt.verify(token, config.JWT_SECRET, function(err, decoded) {      
          if (err) {
              console.log(err);
            return res.json({ success: false, message: 'Failed to authenticate token.' });    
          } else {
            req.decoded = decoded;    
            next();
            res.render("user");
          }
        });

      } else {
        return res.status(403).json({ 
            success: false, 
            message: 'No token provided.' 
        });

      }
    });

router.get("/user", (req,res)=>{
    res.render("user");
});




module.exports = router;
```

As template engine I'm using Handlebars.So with registration everything okay,but when I'm trying to authenticate server brings

> Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

I know that I can use cookies,but I want to keep away from that.
Sorry for language mistakes, and Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

It means that you are sending multiple response to your client side.

I think you just need to delete your `res.render("user");` in your last middleware like this :

```
router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.headers);
    let token = req.body.token || req.headers['auth'] || req.query.token || req.cookies.Authorization;
    // console.log(token);
      if (token) {
        jwt.verify(token, config.JWT_SECRET, function(err, decoded) {      
          if (err) {
              console.log(err);
            return res.json({ success: false, message: 'Failed to authenticate token.' });    
          } else {
            req.decoded = decoded; 
            // Go next and delete res   
            next(); 
            // res.render("user");
          }
        });

      } else {
        return res.status(403).json({ 
            success: false, 
            message: 'No token provided.' 
        });

      }
    });
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: These all are Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V effects.Thank you very much for very fast and effective answer.)))))))))))))))I'll check out it as right.